# How to get rid of this URLs for product page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, configuration, catalog, url-rewrite

Currently, I am working on site, where I am facing following issue related URLs.

when I open a product page, In the browser, following URL gets displayed:

```
https://zitomer-upgrade.aastaging.us/catalog/product/view/id/5388/s/ot-mens-coarse-and-fine-tooth-comb/category/60/
```

But, I want the URL in the following format instead of above URL format:

```
https://zitomer-upgrade.aastaging.us/[category-of-product]/[product-url-key]
```

Is there any configuration required in the backend (admin site)? or any other way is there?

I am using Magento 2.1.9

I have done following:

> Store --> Configuration --> Catalog --> Catalog --> Search Engine
>   Optimization --> Use Categories Path for Product URLs --> 'No'

still it is not working

Can anyone guide on this?

Answer (score 0):

Magento2 admin **Stores->Configuration->General->Web->Search Engine Optimization->**

set ***Use Web Server Rewrites: yes***

then flush cache and reindex in your root folder

```
php bin/magento c:f

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Stores->Configuration->General->Web->Search Engine Optimization->

set Use Web Server Rewrites: yes

this configuration is already present.

Comment: did you do cache flush and reindexing?

Comment: yes, even also done re-indexing

Comment: in mysql delete the table "delete from  url_rewrite"; try to reindex. it will work

Comment: let me try...  the solution

Comment: please take backup before doing this

Comment: install the module https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites. it will help you regenerate. see this blog https://mage2-blog.com/magento-2-regenerate-url-rewrites/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79024/discussion-between-vishnunath-and-rk1990).